# SqlException has different constructors for the same System.Data version

Tags: .net

I have the following two machines with the .net framework versions installed:

```
Machine A
-------------
v4.0.30319
v3.5
v3.0
v2.0.50727
v1.1.4322
v1.0.3705

Machine B
-------------
v4.5
v4.0.30319
v3.5
v3.0
v2.0.50727
v1.1.4322
v1.0.3705
```

When decompiling System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0 using dotpeek on Machine A, I get the following:

```
// Type: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
// Assembly: System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
// Assembly location: c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll

namespace System.Data.SqlClient
{
    private SqlException(string message, SqlErrorCollection errorCollection)
    {
    }
}
```

When decompiling System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0 using dotpeek on Machine B, I get the following:

```
// Type: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
// Assembly: System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
// Assembly location: c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll

namespace System.Data.SqlClient
{
    private SqlException(string message, SqlErrorCollection errorCollection, Exception innerException, Guid conId)
      : base(message, innerException)
    {
    }
}
```

As you can see `SqlException` has different constructors even though the `System.Data` versions appear to be the same. I suspect the reason is that Machine B has .NET 4.5 installed, however I don't understand how a dll with same Version and PublicKeyToken can have different implementations of the same class.

Can anyone confirm that this class did change between 4.0 and 4.5 ?

Also, isn't an in-place upgrade dangerous? I was using reflection to create an instance of a SqlException and now this is suddenly broken by installing a later version of the framework.

Comment: .net 4.5 is an in-place upgrade for .net 4.0. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETVersioningAndMultiTargetingNET45IsAnInplaceUpgradeToNET40.aspx

Comment: If you are using undocumented features using reflection, you are on your own. No one can give you a guarantee about future compatibility.

Comment: I agree with regards to future versions of a dll, but to have code that is referencing the same dll to break depending on which machine it is running on seems dangerous. Doesn't this mean you can't rely on reflection at all ?

Comment: When using private implementation details, like this, no, you really can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you edited your posting with two new questions. I'll try to address them here.

> Can anyone confirm that this class did change between 4.0 and 4.5 ?

You can confirm it yourself:

- Download [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)
- Download [offline installer for .net 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/confirmation.aspx?id=17718)
- Download [offline installer for .net 4.5.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40779)
- Open the 4.0 download with 7zip
- Find netfx_Core.mzz inside of it and open in with 7zip
- Extract system_data_dll_amd64/system_data_dll_x86
- Repeat the above with the 4.5.1 download, use netfx_Full_GDR.mzz instead of netfx_Core.mzz

Now you can open the extracted files with your choice of reverse engineering tool, reflector, dotPeek, ILSpy, or anything else. Report back the results.

> Also, isn't an in-place upgrade dangerous? I was using reflection to
>   create an instance of a SqlException and now this is suddenly broken
>   by installing a later version of the framework.

What is dangerous (read non future-proof) is using undocumented functionality in a way it was not intended to be used. No one can forbid you doing that but if you do, you are on your own: the manufacturer does not give any guarantee about private implementation details.

Answer (score 2):

It is because the implementation is private.  Since the `SqlException` constructor is private, no code outside of the `SqlException` class can call it.  It is then an internal implementation of the DLL that does not affect any external code.

So while the implementation of the DLL has changed, none of the public interfaces have changed so it is fully compatible with the previous version.  Perhaps the change is to fix some bug in the existing version.

The DLL is meant to be a drop in replacement of the existing DLL.  For that it work it has to have the same version and token as the previous version for any existing code to use it without having to be re-compiled.

Answer (score 0):

In .Net 4.5 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException has a new overload for the method CreateException.

```
internal static SqlException CreateException(SqlErrorCollection errorCollection, string serverVersion)
```

and

```
internal static SqlException CreateException(SqlErrorCollection errorCollection, string serverVersion, Guid conId, Exception innerException = null)
```

Choose the one that suits you.